# What is the equivalent of $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] in Deno?

Tags: javascript, typescript, deno

I am new to Deno and I was wondering what the equivalent variable of the PHP variable `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` would be?

I tried countless functions which were returned as "not a function".

Comment: @TJ. Crowder, I am using Deno.

Comment: Thanks. Deno has a couple of different [web server APIs](https://deno.land/manual/runtime/http_server_apis#http-server-apis) (and then there are frameworks built on top of them). Which are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deno has a couple of different [web server APIs](https://deno.land/manual/runtime/http_server_apis#http-server-apis) (and then there are frameworks built on top of them). But I think most (all?) of them provide the handler with a [`Request` object](https://deno.land/api?s=Request), which has a [`url`](https://deno.land/api?s=Request#prop_url) property telling you what the requested URL was.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can have a global variable storing the request URL because it works in a different way than Deno.

In Deno, you usually get the URL inside of some request handler function in one of its parameters, **but** you usually don't even need that if you are using any framework to help you handling those requests (see examples below).

Using the bare `serve` utility from the `std` library, you can handle requests like this:

```
import { serve } from "https://deno.land/std@0.183.0/http/server.ts";

function handler(req: Request): Response {
    console.log("Request URL:", req.url);
    return new Response("Response: OK");
}

serve(handler);
```

In the above example the `req.url` exists because it was passed to this `handler()` function every time it was invoked (for every request) because this function was registered as a handler for all requests by invoking `serve(handler);`

If you save it as `main.ts` then you can run this program with:

```
deno run --allow-net main.ts
```

The default port is 8000 so you can run curl to make a request like this:

```
deno run --allow-net main.ts
```

which will display:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/abc
```

Now, this is quite low level API and in practice you would probably want to use a library like oak. E.g. to have an equivalent server using oak, which works differently than `serve` from thee previous example, you'd use something like this:

```
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";

const app = new Application();

app.use((ctx) => {
  console.log("Request URL:", ctx.request.url.href);
  ctx.response.body = "Response: OK";
});

await app.listen({ port: 8000 });
```

So here, you access the URL not be `req.url` but with `ctx.request.url.href` (or starting with something else than `ctx` if you named your parameter differently). The `.href` is here to get the full URL as a string because `ctx.request.url` is an object - an instance of URL).

**But** you usuall don't access your URL lik that, but instead you define routes with separate handlers that get run for the specific URLs, e.g.:

```
import { Application, Router } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";

const router = new Router();
router
  .get("/abc", (context) => {
    // we know that so we can hardcode it ...
    console.log("Request for: /abc");
    context.response.body = "Response from /abc";
  })
  .get("/def", (context) => {
    // ... or we can access the context
    console.log("Request for:", context.request.url.pathname);
    context.response.body = "Response from /def";
    
  });

const app = new Application();
app.use(router.routes());
app.use(router.allowedMethods());

await app.listen({ port: 8000 });
```

Note that we don't have to test the URL inside of those handlers but of course we can. They already know which URL they are serving because the `oak` library runs them for the correct routes that they need to serve.

So it all depends on what libraries of framework you are using to handle the requests - which you would usually do for production code instead of using the `serve` directly (unless you have some very specific needs).

To find a good framework for for your needs, see:

- https://deno.land/manual@v1.28.0/getting_started/web_frameworks
- https://github.com/denolib/awesome-deno#web-framework